# Satellite layer for OpenLayers 3 (except Google)

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3, bing, mapquest, satellite

I am looking for a satellite layer (except Google) which runs with OpenLayers 3. According to the examples, it should be possible to connect OL3 with Bing satellite, MapQuest satellite or OSM satellite. However, the provided examples do not work anymore. [Bing satellite](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/bing-maps.html?q=bing) does not work at all and the supply of MapQuest tiles stops once I have reached a specific zoom level.

Am I the only one with this type of problem? Did I missed something or just took something not into account?

2 Years ago, I was programming on a project, which included OpenLayers 2. With OL2, it was possible to create a map referring to the Bing satellite layer as well as the OSM satellite layer. It worked without any trouble. Since then, they shut down all this services.

Does anyone has had the same problem and got a solution? I would very appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as "OSM satellite". OpenStreetMap does not provide any aerial imagery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bing does work. See the [bing-maps example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/bing-maps.html) from the latest release. Make sure to get your own API key from http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ when you use Bing layers in OpenLayers.

The reason why the Bing layer is not displayed in the example you linked is because the API key is expired there.

Comment: It's still so simple, thanks a lot. After creating a valid API-Key, I was able to access the Bing layers again.